# How can I make a widget similar to the media library, just for other entities?

Tags: views, media, 9

I want to make widgets similar to the one that is provided by media library, but just for other entities, for instance [Bibliography & Citation](https://www.drupal.org/project/bibcite) or even just other content. Is it possible to build similar widgets using configuration or is custom code needed?

Comment: This question does not really fit for DA, but you might take a look at this blog post to got some ideas: https://www.electriccitizen.com/citizen-blog/media-libraries-drupal-8 Even though this is no-code, this is pretty advanced configuration stuff and requires a good basis of Drupal knowledge

Comment: The blog is a bit older (pre Drupal media library) and covers Media objects, but [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) can be used for any entity

Comment: Yep, [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser).